# Bootstrap 5 modal getting only the first value from *ngFor

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have child component that is getting the values passed into the Input property for the CARD section but not into the MODAL section - modal gets always the values from the first object from the array.
On the other hand in the method getTemplateData(template: ITemplate) the console.log returns the correct object
The values are coming from the parent component from an *NgFor loop.

ITemplate

child.ts

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() templateObject: ITemplate = {};

  constructor(private componentCommunicationService: ComponentCommunicationService,
    private router: Router) { }


  getTemplateData(template: ITemplate) {
    this.templateObject = template;
    console.log(this.templateObject);
    return this.templateObject;
  }

  showOrder() {
    this.componentCommunicationService.sendFlag(false);
    this.router.navigate(
      ['/orders'],
      {
        queryParams: { order: this.templateObject.Title, Id: this.templateObject.TemplateId }
      }

    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

child.html

```
<!--CARD-->
<div class="w-100 card-wrapper-scroll">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{templateObject.Title}}</h5>            
            <p class="card-text">{{templateObject.Description}}</p>
            <a (click)="showOrder()" class="btn btn-secondary">Alege modelul</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal" (click)="getTemplateData(templateObject)">
                <i>Inspect</i> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<--END CARD-->
<!--MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">{{templateObject.Title}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Description - {{templateObject.Description}}
                Id - {{templateObject.TemplateId}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Choose</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<--END MODAL-->
```

parent.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, HostListener, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BackendService } from 'app/services/backend/backend.service';
import { BehaviorSubject, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, Observable, of, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ITemplate } from '../../models/ITemplate.interface';
import { SpinnerService } from 'app/services/spinner/spinner.service';
import { GetScreenResolutionService } from 'app/services/get-screen-resolution/get-screen-resolution.service';
import { LimitNumberOfObjectsService } from 'app/services/limit-no-objects/limit-number-of-objects.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'templates-container',
  templateUrl: './templates-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./templates-container.component.css']
})
export class TemplatesContainerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  totalNumberOfTemplates: number = 0;
  Suggestions$: Observable<ITemplate[]> = new Observable();
  C$: Observable<ITemplate[]> = new Observable();
  backendServiceSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  searchTemplateInputField = new FormControl('');
  displaySpinner$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = this._spinnerService.spinnerBooleanState;
  numberOfCardsByScreenResolution$: BehaviorSubject<number> = this._numberOfObjectsInViewByScrRes$.setNumberOfObjectsAtngOnInit;
  numberOfCardsByScreenResolution: number = 0;
  numberOfSuggestionsObjectsByScreenRes$: BehaviorSubject<number> = this._numberOfObjectsInViewByScrRes$.setNumberOfSuggestionsObjects;
  numberOfSuggestionsObjectsByScreenRes: number = 0;


  constructor(
    private _backendService: BackendService,    
    private _spinnerService: SpinnerService,
    private _numberOfObjectsInViewByScrRes$: GetScreenResolutionService,
    private _limitNumberOfObjectsService: LimitNumberOfObjectsService,
    ) { }



  getKeyboardInput() {
    return this.searchTemplateInputField.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(keyBoardInput => {
        this._backendService.listTemplates(this.numberOfCardsByScreenResolution, keyBoardInput?.toLowerCase())
          .subscribe((cardsHttpResponse: ITemplate[]) => {
            this.C$ = this._limitNumberOfObjectsService.display_N_Objects(cardsHttpResponse, this.numberOfCardsByScreenResolution);
            if (keyBoardInput?.toLowerCase != null) {
              this.Suggestions$ = this._limitNumberOfObjectsService.display_N_Objects(cardsHttpResponse, this.numberOfSuggestionsObjectsByScreenRes);
            }
            return;
          });

      });
  }


  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    let keyDownEvent$: Subject<KeyboardEvent> = new BehaviorSubject(event);
    keyDownEvent$.subscribe(keyEvent => {
      if (keyEvent.code === 'Backspace' || keyEvent.code === 'Escape') {
        this.searchTemplateInputField.reset();
        this.Suggestions$ = of([]);
      }
    });
  }

  trackByFn(index: number, item: ITemplate) {
    return item.TemplateId;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.numberOfCardsByScreenResolution$.subscribe(numberOfCards => this.numberOfCardsByScreenResolution = numberOfCards);
    this.numberOfSuggestionsObjectsByScreenRes$.subscribe(numberOfSuggestions => this.numberOfSuggestionsObjectsByScreenRes = numberOfSuggestions);
    this._backendService.listTemplates(this.numberOfCardsByScreenResolution, null)
      .subscribe((cardsHttpResponse) => {        
        this.C$ = this._limitNumberOfObjectsService.display_N_Objects(cardsHttpResponse, this.numberOfCardsByScreenResolution); this.totalNumberOfTemplates = Number(cardsHttpResponse[0].NumberOfTemplates)
      });
    this.getKeyboardInput();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.backendServiceSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.getKeyboardInput().unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

parent.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row margin-b-40">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h2>Modele recente</h2>
      <p>Cauta-ti afacerea, de exemplu... </p>
      <ng-container>
        <p>Total modele disponibile - {{totalNumberOfTemplates}}</p>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="displaySpinner$ | async">
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light justify-content-left col-lg-4">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="restaurant japonez"
          aria-label="Cauta" id="searchTemplate" [formControl]="searchTemplateInputField">
      </nav>
      <ng-container *ngIf="Suggestions$ | async">
        <p>Sugestii</p>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let card of Suggestions$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn">{{card.Title}}</li>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-deck mt-2"></div>


  <div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let template of C$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 my-5">
        <app-card-component [templateObject]="template"></app-card-component>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your interface and the parent component!

Comment: can you add a stackblitz? its easier to find the issue when i can simulate the project.